# Error using node-soap in NodeJS

Tags: xml, node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to consume a WSDL with node-soap. I use it as follows in my controller:

```
this.getSoap = function (request, response) {
var soap = require('node-soap');

var url = 'http://identificacion.uci.cu/servicios/v5/servicios.php';
var args = { IdExpediente: '016381' };

soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
    client.ObtenerFotoDadoIdExpediente(args, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err
            client.describe();
        } else
            console.log(result);
    });
});

return response.render('index', {
    variable: 'valor'
    });
};
```

And when I call I get this response in the browser:

> Object function SOAPClient(options, fn) { fn = this.fn = fn; options =
>   this.options = _.extend({}, defaults, options); var deferred;
>   this.namespaces = ''; this.methods = ''; this.body = function
>   (options) { return "" +
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\/\" " +
>   "xmlns:xsi=\"[http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance\](http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance%5C)" " +
>   "xmlns:xsd=\"[http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema\](http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema%5C)" " + options.namespaces
>   + ">" + "" + options.methods + "" + ''; }; this.newRequest(); return this; } has no
>   method 'createClient'

```
TypeError: Object function SOAPClient(options, fn) {
fn = this.fn = fn;
options = this.options = _.extend({}, defaults, options);

var deferred;

this.namespaces = '';
this.methods = '';
this.body = function (options) {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
        "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope " +
        "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope\/\" " +
        "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance\" " +
        "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema\" " +
        options.namespaces +
        ">" +

        "<SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
            options.methods +
        "</SOAP-ENV:Body>" +

    '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
};

this.newRequest();

return this;
} has no method 'createClient'
at Object.getSoap (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/src/SoapModule  /controller/soapController.js:19:10)
at module.exports (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/src/SoapModule/resources/config/routing.js:16:20)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
at next (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
at /home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22
at Function.proto.process_params (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
at next (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
at expressInit (/home/heimdall/Proyectos/myNODE/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:23:5)
```

I use this documentation: [Github project](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap)

---

Now my file look that:

```
var soap = require('soap');

// url del wsdl
this.getSoap = function (request, response) {
var url = 'http://identificacion.uci.cu/servicios/v5/servicios.php';
var args = { IdExpediente: '016381' };

soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        client.ObtenerFotoDadoIdExpediente(args, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err
                client.describe();
            } else
                console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
```

And obtain this in my server:

**Cannot set property 'descriptions' of null**

Answer (score 1):

First things first -- when an error is thrown specifying an object "has no method," and we expect there to be one by the given name, this typically suggests the object (or class) failed to be defined properly via the definition or an incorrect require statement (not necessarily that you're using it improperly).

Looking at the documentation link you've provided, the initial item that stands out to me to be causing this issue is the `require('node-soap');` statement. While the project is called "node-soap" on github, the require statements provided in the documentation indicate that the package is by the name of "soap".

Try replacing:

```
var soap = require('node-soap');
```

With:

```
var soap = require('soap');
```

Also, the Node.js community considers it best practice to not `require()` packages within functions, but rather outside of any functions or class definitions, such as at the top of the source file.

Let us know if that solves the issue -- cheers.

### Edit (question has updated code):

This is a separate issue (your first one has been solved):

From the documentation, the `client.describe()` method is used to offer a "description of services, ports and methods as a JavaScript object."

The tests show usage of the `.describe()` method to only be legal if the assertion is made that an error does not exist. Your code currently attempts to use the `describe()` method when an error exists.

```
if (err) {
    throw err
    client.describe();
}
```

Your new error is `Cannot set property 'descriptions' of null` now because an object hasn't been provided to create definitions on, likely there is an error along the connection, try checking if your url is valid (i.e. sending back a response the soap package can work with), otherwise there isn't anything to `describe()`.

Comment: I modified the file contain and the response. Please look at.

Answer (score 0):

Well i change de url of the web service:

Before:
http://identificacion.uci.cu/servicios/v5/servicios.php

After:
http://rhoda.uci.cu/roa.php/interoperability/session?wsdl

And the error dissapears, may be this module only work for **?wsdl** and not for **.php**

Answer (score 0):

You must check, than you soap endpoint finish  with the next structure

serviceURL = http://localhost:8080/Evaluator?wsdl

also check this

```
enter code here

await soap.createClient(serviceURL, (err: any, client: any) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      client[method](payload, (errr: any, result: any) => {
        if (errr) {
          reject(errr)
        } else {
          resolve(result)
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

I hope than this worked for you!